# Is an element attribute a node or not?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

According to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_navigation.asp tutorial, element attributes are also nodes. In the example below, script is showing only element nodes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="#">link</a>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var n = document.body.childNodes;
var s = "";
for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
  s += n[i].nodeName + "<br>";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = s;
</script>
some text

</body>
</html>
```

The result (node names) is:

```
#text
A
#text
P
#text
SCRIPT
```

I guess #text is node name for line breaks etc (but I have no idea why text after SCRIPT is not shown as #text).

Why it's not showing `href` attribute? Even when I try to see all child nodes of anchor element, it's showing only text node inside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Yes, they are nodes, but they are treated differently.

From the [DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-637646024):

> `Attr` objects inherit the `Node` interface, but since they are not actually child nodes of the element they describe, the DOM does not consider them part of the document tree. Thus, the `Node` attributes `parentNode`, `previousSibling`, and `nextSibling` have a `null` value for `Attr` objects. The DOM takes the view that attributes are properties of elements rather than having a separate identity from the elements they are associated with; this should make it more efficient to implement such features as default attributes associated with all elements of a given type. Furthermore, `Attr` nodes may not be immediate children of a `DocumentFragment`. However, they can be associated with `Element` nodes contained within a `DocumentFragment`. In short, users and implementors of the DOM need to be aware that `Attr` nodes have some things in common with other objects inheriting the `Node` interface, but they also are quite distinct.

As the text says, attribute nodes are not considered to be children of the element, hence they are not contained in `childNodes`. To get the attributes of an element, you can access [**`element.attributes`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes).

Comment: That is, of course from DOM3. In DOM4, attributes are not nodes.

Answer (score 3):

Element attributes are not nodes.

If you [check MDN about `.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) (wich is a far better source that w3schools) you will read:

> The Node.childNodes read-only property returns a live collection of child nodes of the given element.

In the [DOM3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-637646024) one can read:

> Attr objects inherit the Node interface, but since **they are not actually child nodes of the element they describe**, the DOM does not consider them part of the document tree.

About your other question, the reason why you do not see the text after the `<script>`tag is because the DOM is not ready loaded yet. If you put that code in the end, near `</body>`, then everything will be there.